# finding and Importing xml file into python

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I am attempting to import an xml file into python with minidom.

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> import os
>>> xmldoc = minidom.parse('c/Users/WFD/Documents/VXWorks/XML_Parasing_Python')
```

and python cannot find this file even though I have specifically spelled out where it is. I am new to python so if there is a glaring error I apologize but can anyone explain how to import an xml file in mydocments? 
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    xmldoc = minidom.parse('c/Users/WFD/Documents/VXWorks/XML_Parasing_Python')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parse
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c/Users/WFD/Documents/VXWorks/XML_Parasing_Python'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the path you are giving is not correct: for Windows, the proper way to format an absolute file path is:

```
blah("C:/Users/WFD/Documents/VXWorks/XML_Parasing_Python")
```

Also, `XML_Parasing_Python` may be mispelled; it probably should be `XML_Parsing_Python`.

You can use the [`os.path` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) for more cross-platform scripts.